# A function to manipulate data.frames in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to come up with a function that does the following to a `data.frame` outputting a new `data.frame` with the same names:

**1-** Creates a `seq(min(target), max(target), .1)`.

**2-** Takes the *mean of all other* variables.

For example, if `q` is our `data.frame`, and `jen` is the `target` in it, I want to reformat `q` such that `jen`'s data becomes `seq(min(jen), max(jen), .1)`, and both `bob` and `joe` just change to their mean values.

Is it possible to do this in R?

I tried something but it is far from being accurate.

```
q = data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3, joe = 5:9)


change <- function(dataframe = q, target = "jen"){

n <- names(dataframe)

dataframe[target] <- seq(from = min(target), max(target), .1)

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R solution. My idea is to create the target column first in the function, and then use a for-loop to add the mean of other columns.

```
# Example data frame
q <- data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3, joe = 5:9)

# Create then function
change <- function(dat, target){
  vec <- dat[, target]
  target_new <- seq(min(vec), max(vec), by = 0.1)
  dat2 <- data.frame(target_new)
  names(dat2) <- target
  for (i in names(dat)[!names(dat) %in% target]){
    dat2[[i]] <- mean(dat[[i]]) 
  }
  dat2 <- dat2[, names(dat)]
  return(dat2)
}

# Apply the function
change(q, "jen")

#    bob  jen joe
# 1    0 -1.3   7
# 2    0 -1.2   7
# 3    0 -1.1   7
# 4    0 -1.0   7
# 5    0 -0.9   7
# 6    0 -0.8   7
# 7    0 -0.7   7
# 8    0 -0.6   7
# 9    0 -0.5   7
# 10   0 -0.4   7
# 11   0 -0.3   7
# 12   0 -0.2   7
# 13   0 -0.1   7
# 14   0  0.0   7
# 15   0  0.1   7
# 16   0  0.2   7
# 17   0  0.3   7
# 18   0  0.4   7
# 19   0  0.5   7
# 20   0  0.6   7
# 21   0  0.7   7
# 22   0  0.8   7
# 23   0  0.9   7
# 24   0  1.0   7
# 25   0  1.1   7
# 26   0  1.2   7
# 27   0  1.3   7
# 28   0  1.4   7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `base R`

```
data.frame(Map(function(x, y)  if(x=="mean") get(x)(y) else 
    get(x)(min(y), max(y), by = 0.1), setNames(c("mean", "seq", "mean"), names(q)), q))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
q %>%
  summarise(bob = mean(bob), 
            jen = list(seq(min(jen), max(jen), by = 0.1)), 
            joe = mean(joe)) %>% 
  unnest
```

Or if there are many columns to get the `mean` and only a single column sequence, then instead of specifying one by one

```
q %>%
  mutate_at(c(1,3), mean) %>%
  group_by(bob, joe) %>%
  summarise(jen = list(seq(min(jen), max(jen), by = 0.1))) %>% 
  unnest
```

Or use `complete`

```
q %>%
    group_by(bob = mean(bob), joe = mean(joe)) %>%
    complete(jen = seq(min(jen), max(jen), by = .1))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will upvote yours, but adopted the first answer! Thank you again & God bless!

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses colMeans function and repeats the result as many times as the sequence is long. Then I replace the target column with the sequence results.

```
q = data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3, joe = 5:9)

manip <- function(target, df){
  t.column <- which(colnames(df) == target)
  dfmeans <- colMeans(df)
  minmax <- range(df[,t.column],na.rm = T)
  t.seq <- seq(minmax[1],minmax[2],.1)
  newdf <- matrix(dfmeans, ncol = length(dfmeans))[rep(1, length(t.seq)),]
  newdf[,t.column] <- t.seq
  colnames(newdf) <- colnames(df)
  return(as.data.frame(newdf))
}
manip("jen",q)
```